# Неверно показывает тип/размер загруженного файла

Tags: php

Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Загружаю gif, вывожу его данные (размер/тип) через $_FILES['file']['type'] и $_FILES['file']['size'], но вот что выдает скрипт:
размер 0, тип файла == ''

Возможно это связано с тем, что размер гифки > 1мб? Проверял на нескольких гифках, с небольшим размером грузятся нормально.

Comment: print_r($_FILES['file']) выводит массив с данными?Что именно?

Comment: Да, выводит. 
Array ( [name] => name.gif [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте в файле php.ini максимальный размер загружаемого файла. (или phpinfo поле - upload_max_filesize) а так же макс размер POST запросов

Comment: Блин, спасибо. Чето тупанул, не подумал сначала. Увеличил параметр, теперь все ок.